# Recording replies in discord PMs

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am currently working on making an application bot in discord, and made a quick test to try to find a way to detect a reply in a PM channel between a user and my bot. After fiddling around with varying google searches and such, my best attempt was this:

```
    [Command("apply")]
    public async Task ApplyAsync()
    {
        var user = Context.User as IGuildUser;
        await user.SendMessageAsync("Test");

        if (Context.Message.Content != null)
        {
            await user.SendMessageAsync($"You replied {Context.Message.Content}");
        }
    }
```

Still being somewhat new to c#, I figured this would take the message content of the users reply to the private message, but it just throws in ".apply", and I have't been able to figure out how to get the bot to actually detect a reply in a PM.

Comment: You can check if your Context.Channel Is an Private Channel. If this is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the command in DMs, you have to change the line `var user = Context.User as IGuildUser;` to `var user = Context.User as IUser;` This is what caused the exception.